# Perl: Calling a module method inside [ ]

Tags: perl

Using an example, let a perl program start in the following fashion:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes;
```

What's the difference between

```
 my $request_start_epoch = [Time::HiRes::gettimeofday];
```

and

```
 my $request_start_epoch = Time::HiRes::gettimeofday;
```

?

Comment: What do you think the difference is?

Comment: `Time::HiRes::gettimeofday` returns two integers (whole seconds since the epoch, microseconds since the beginning of the current second) in list context and a floating-point number (seconds since the epoch) in scalar context.

Comment: I took the liberty to boil that code down to the core of the question by removing the constructorish code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former calls the function in list context, assembles an anonymous array containing the elements of the returned list, and sets `$request_start_epoch` to a reference to that array.

The latter calls the function in scalar context and stores its return-value in `$request_start_epoch`.

These will almost always be different; the only time they would be the same is if the function's behavior in scalar context is to wrap up its list-context results in an anonymous array and return a reference to it. I've never seen any method written like that, but I'm sure someone somewhere has done it at some point!

Comment: I've seen some blushing abuses of `wantarray`.

Comment: @ruakh thanks for the explanation. i somehow got the idea that for this case the former is more natural..

Comment: although per cpan "gettimeofday Returns a 2 element array with the second and microseconds since the epoch." so i'd go for the later

Answer (score 0):

The brackets [] convert what is returned by gettimeofday to an array reference. In your case, it would be a one element array.

Creating an array reference.

```
    $arr_ref = [ 1,2,3,4,5 ];
```

Deferencing it.

```
    @{ $arr_ref };
```

Accessing an element.

```
    $ { $array_ref }[0]
```

Comment: I think it's more common to write `@$arr_ref` and `$arr_ref->[0]`.